# Login failed error. Need to user service account

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to implement a SSIS package and getting login failed error for windows account when trying to execute it manually.

The SSIS package calls a stored proc from one server which has storedproc that calls a view from another server.

I basically need a service account to query the view which I am able to do from sql management studio's query analyser login as different user and providing my service account details however I am not able execute it from SSIS.

I have created a dataflow with source and destination. The current connection manager uses my windows credentials to access which is giving me an error. When I try to specify my service account username and password in the existing connection, it doesnt accept it.

How do I set my connection to user the service account instead of windows account.

Comment: By changing the properties in your connection manager???

Comment: How do I select or specify  the service account in connection manager.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140282.aspx

Comment: I have created a credential and proxy for executing the SSIS but how do I execute the package manually. For eg when I click the preview button on the source I get an error

Comment: No clue...what is the error message?

Comment: Error at Process getName. An Oledb error has occured. An Oledb record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Login failed for user xxxx. Unable to retrieve column information

Comment: Have you tried searching for that error message? It is nearly impossible to debug a connection issue like this remotely. There could be a number of reasons for this.

Comment: I guess you haven't understood my issue or I am not clear in my explanation. The storeprocedure that I am trying to execute is trying to access a view on another server which basically needs service account to execute. If I log using management studio to the source database via a service account where the stored proc resides , I am able to execute the stored proc manually.

Comment: As with regards the SSIS pacakge it is in visual studio. If I try to open the connection manager, I have two options windows user account and sa account. I cant use both as need to provide service account. The error I am getting is when I provide the service account user name and password in sa input controls. Which is incorrect

Comment: I need to preview the data in the designer and map the source and destination fields.

Comment: You could use EXECUTE AS in the procedure. This would mean that the procedure always executes as a specific user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql

Comment: I added the execute as statement in the storedproc to execute as service account but that doesnt seem to make any difference. I get a message Unable to retrieve column information from the datasource.Make sure your target table in the database is available

Comment: I get this error when I execute it manually in the database Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.